# Searching AWS AutoScalingGroup resources by tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm searching for autoscaling groups by tags - all of our AWS resources have a number of tags applied to them. However I only want to find auto scaling groups, not other types of resources.

The should be possible using the tagging API; from the command-line:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters=autoscaling
```

However, this results in the error: **`Unsupported service=autoscaling in ResourceTypeFilter`**. It works fine for other resource type filters such as `ec2`.
(Note that providing the more specific `--resource-type-filters=autoscaling:autoScalingGroup` results in the same error)

I've also noticed that if I actually search for tags without restricting the resource type to autoscaling, I do not get any autoscaling group ARNs in the response.

Is there any (other) way to search for auto scaling groups by tags in the AWS APIs?

The reason is that I want to create custom metrics for a range of services and I need to find the correct auto scaling groups by a specific set of tags, to be able to retrieve and put CloudWatch metrics with the AutoScalingGroupName metric dimension for each.

Comment: Hi Erwin, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @Mlu why do you think I haven't upvoted it? I did of course, it's a good answer.But it answers part of the question - it provides an alternative. I hope to find out why I can't use the resource tagging API for this - being able to search looks like one of the primary reasons for having tags in the first place.

Comment: I have updated my answer - it's an API limitation, you won't be able to use `aws recourcegroupstaggingapi` for AutoScaling Groups unless Amazon adds this support to the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `aws recourcegroupstaggingapi` simply because this API *doesn't support AutoScaling Groups* at the moment. That's also why AutoScaling info is not returned in `get-resources` results as you noticed. See [Resource Groups Tagging » API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) for the actual API and supported resources. Note that AutoScaling *is not* part of the EC2 API. Why this limitation? I don't know, you'll have to ask Amazon ;)

However with a bit bit of `jq` hackery you can use `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups` as a workaround:

```
~ $ aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups | jq -r '
        ## Unfold .Tags[] to .TagKey = Value
        .[keys[0]] | map(
            if has("Tags") then 
                . += (.Tags | map( { "Tag\(.Key)": (.Value) } ) | add | del(.Tags))
            else
                .
            end
        )[] | 
        ## TagKey == Value you want to select on (e.g. Name=="wiki-3" in my case)
        select(.TagName == "wiki-3") |
        ## The attribute you want to output (e.g. .AutoScalingGroupName or .AutoScalingGroupARN)
        .AutoScalingGroupName
'
```

Hope that helps :)